# ScaleAnimation applied only to parent view

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout(parent view) and a few child view (imageviews and textviews) inside this relative layout.

I am applying scale animation on parent view in order to get zoom in effect. The only problem is that when scale animation is applied to parent view its child view also scales.
Is there any why to stop child from animation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will have to set the image/background of the parent `ViewGroup` as a separate `View` and apply the animation to that to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this. Don't know if it is the best way, but it works and looks ok. I am using the animation from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA, but instead of image, I have a ViewGroup with 3 TextViews.

I have a blue container with 3 TextViews: name, address and key. The container starts from the size of a GridView cell, and expands to the width of the entire screen, moving from the location of the cell to the top of the screen. To do this without having the TextViews resized also, I am animating both the blue background which resizes, and the ViewGroup which does not resize, but only translates.

In my layout I have divided the background to a separate view, and left the ViewGroup with the TextViews displayed on top (included them into a RelativeLayout):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/outter_margin">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/title_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/activity_login_application_name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/container"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/container"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/key"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    ....
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in the activity, I am animating both. First in onViewCreated I set their starting dimensions and scale factors (see link above for more details):

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = titleBg.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        titleBg.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

        // Figure out where the background view and full size versions are, relative
        // to the screen and each other
        int[] screenLocation = new int[2];
        titleBg.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation);
        mLeftDelta = leftCoordinate - screenLocation[0];
        mTopDelta = topCoordinate - screenLocation[1];

        //set TextViews container a fix width
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = container.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        container.setLayoutParams(params);

        // Scale factors View Group to make the large version the same size as the initial one from GridView, width scale is 1
        mWidthScale = (float) 1;
        mHeightScale = (float) height / container.getHeight();

        // Scale factors background View to make the large version the same size as the initial one from GridView
        mWidthScaleBG = (float) width / titleBg.getWidth();
        mHeightScaleBG = (float) height / titleBg.getHeight();

        runEnterAnimation();

        return true;
    }
});
```

with animations:

```
public void runEnterAnimation() {
    // Set starting values for properties we're going to animate. These
    // values scale and position the full size version down to the thumbnail
    // size/location, from which we'll animate it back up
    container.setPivotX(0);
    container.setPivotY(0);
    container.setScaleX(mWidthScale);
    container.setScaleY(mHeightScale);
    container.setTranslationX(mLeftDelta);
    container.setTranslationY(mTopDelta);

    titleBg.setPivotX(0);
    titleBg.setPivotY(0);
    titleBg.setScaleX(mWidthScaleBG);
    titleBg.setScaleY(mHeightScaleBG);
    titleBg.setTranslationX(mLeftDelta);
    titleBg.setTranslationY(mTopDelta);

    // Animate scale and translation of Bg to go from initial to full size
    titleBg.animate().setDuration(duration).
           scaleX(1).scaleY(1).
           translationX(0).translationY(0).
           setInterpolator(sDecelerator);

    // Animate scale and translation of ViewGroup to go from initial to full size
    container.animate().setDuration(duration).
           scaleX(1).scaleY(1).
           translationX(0).translationY(0).
           setInterpolator(sDecelerator).
           withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                        .....
                  }
           });

}

public void runExitAnimation(final Runnable endAction) {

     final boolean fadeOut;
     if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != orientation) {
         container.setPivotX(width / 2);
         container.setPivotY(container.getHeight() / 2);

         titleBg.setPivotX(titleBg.getWidth() / 2);
         titleBg.setPivotY(titleBg.getHeight() / 2);

         mLeftDelta = 0;
         mTopDelta = 0;
         fadeOut = true;
     } else {
         fadeOut = false;
     }

    // Animate ViewGroup back to initial size/location
    container.animate().setDuration(duration).
              scaleX(mWidthScale).scaleY(mHeightScale).
              translationX(mLeftDelta).translationY(mTopDelta).
              withEndAction(endAction);

    titleBg.animate().setDuration(duration).
              scaleX(mWidthScaleBG).scaleY(mHeightScaleBG).
              translationX(mLeftDelta).translationY(mTopDelta);
    if (fadeOut) {
        container.animate().alpha(0);
        titleBg.animate().alpha(0);
    }

}
```